# Pointwise convergence, but not in measure

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Can someone give me an example of $X_n$ such that $X_n \rightarrow X$ ($X: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$) converges pointwise, but $X_n$ doesn't converge to $X$ in measure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take
$$X_n(x):=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{ if }n<x<n+1,\\
0&\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

If there were convergence in measure, it would be to null function (take the restriction to a bounded interval). But $\lambda\{|X_n|>1/2\}=1$ for each $n$.

Comment: Can you explain me, why X_n doesn't converge to X in measure? (pointwise is clear).

Comment: @JohnD I've added the details.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, I think you didn't want "finite" but "larger than a constant"

Comment: @YoniRozenshein Thanks, fixed now.

Comment: Now it's clear :) thank you guys!